# wxwidgets // g++ Compiler error: no matching function for call to 'operator new(..'

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

At the moment I am trying to port a Visual C++ application to Linux. The code compiles without errors in Visual Studio, but I get many compiler errors under Linux. One of these errors is:

```
../src/wktools4.cpp:29: error: no matching function for
call to 'operator new(unsigned int, const char[40], int)'
```

More information:

- IDE: kdevelop with G++
- GUI API:

The error appears at the following line:

```
IMPLEMENT_APP(Cwktools4App)
```

and some other lines.

What am I missing?

Comment: What does the IMPLEMENT_APP macro expand to?  It helps to dump the output from the preprocessor to find compile time errors inside of macros.

Comment: it also happens with e.g. "frame = new Cwktools4Frame;".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the error:

```
#ifdef __WXDEBUG__
#define new WXDEBUG_NEW
#endif
```

When I remove these lines, I don't get the errors any more. The code was generated from a wxwidgets wizard for VisualStudio. I have no idea what it does...

Thank you all for your help! Now I have to fix the linker errors ;)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your Visual C++ app has overloaded `operator new()`.

This is often done (with the additional parameters you see) to add debugging and other analysis info to each memory allocation.

Since you get the error with something as simple as **`frame = new Cwktools4Frame;`** I recommend looking for macros or compiler-level defines that are redefining "new" as something else.  The first place to look should be in debug-specific builds.

Comment: I don't use an overloaded new operator. Maybe in some 3rd party lib (wxwidgets?) they do so. How can I find/resolve this?

Comment: Compile (gcc) the offending file again with a "-E" argument.  That will output what the code looks like after the preprocessor runs its pass and all macros will be expanded.